# Filter dates in table from, to

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have table in my project

I have filtering by date in my table

Now it filters only by Date from value, but I want to filter it from-to dates.

How I can do this in my case?

Here is snippet that demonstrates my problem

```js
 $('#datefilterfrom').change(function () {
        var date = moment(this.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        var filter, table, tr, td, i;
        filter = date.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("testTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date from</h4>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date to</h4>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
        </div>
        </div>
<table id="testTable" class="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>18/07/2018</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>19/07/2018</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
    <td>20/07/2018</td>
    <td>nothing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this is ok

```
function filterRows() {
  var from = $('#datefilterfrom').val();
  var to = $('#datefilterto').val();

  if (!from && !to) { // no value for from and to
    return;
  }

  from = from || '1970-01-01'; // default from to a old date if it is not set
  to = to || '2999-12-31';

  var dateFrom = moment(from);
  var dateTo = moment(to);

  $('#testTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    var val = $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    var dateVal = moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var visible = (dateVal.isBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, null, [])) ? "" : "none"; // [] for inclusive
    $(tr).css('display', visible);
  });
}

$('#datefilterfrom').on("change", filterRows);
$('#datefilterto').on("change", filterRows);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oajc94hf/38/

Comment: Yeah. That's helps.Thanks

Comment: What does 'moment(from)' mean here?