# Filter table rows by date range using date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, range

I tried to filter the ranges with `moment.js` but I acountred some problem to import that library (conflict with others) so, now I want to use instead `date()` constructor, but it doesn't work correctly.

Have you an idea why it doesn't work correctlty ?, Here is my try :

I used `date()` and `getTime()`

Some example that does'nt work when you hit :

from : `01 01 2019` to : `31 12 2019`

```js
$(function(){

  //NAME
  $("#name").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#my-table").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
  
  //FROM
  $("#from").bind("keyup change", function() {
    var value = new Date($(this).val().toLowerCase()).getTime();
    //console.log(value);
    $("#my-table").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle(new Date($(this).find('td:first-child').text()).getTime() >= (value))
      //console.log(new Date($(this).find('td:first-child').text()).getTime());
    });
    
    //clean from
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length === 0) {
      $("#my-table").find('tr').show();
    }
  });
  
  //TO
  $("#to").bind("keyup change", function() {
    var value = new Date($(this).val().toLowerCase()).getTime();
    //console.log(value);
    $("#my-table").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle(new Date($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toLowerCase()).getTime() <= (value))
    });
    
    //clean to
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length === 0) {
      $("#my-table").find('tr').show();
    }
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.container input {
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.list-group {
  border:1px solid #1896f3;
  padding:20px;
}

.list-group td, th {
  border:1px solid #1896f3;
  padding:7px 100px;
  text-align:center;
}

th {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  Date from : <input class="form-control" id="from" type="date">
  to : <input class="form-control" id="to" type="date">
  <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name...">
  <br>
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="my-table">
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2019-11-21</td>
            <td>kal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td >2015-01-01</td>
            <td>blake</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2015-01-30</td>
            <td>secure</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2016-03-10</td>
            <td>home</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2019-05-19</td>
            <td>car</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2014-09-10</td>
            <td>yop</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
            <td>2017-12-30</td>
            <td>wick</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What conflicts did moment have? That statement seems strange

Comment: I working on some framework and this one need to include js via requirejs, this is why I dicided to use `date()` you think that momentjs is indisponsable ?

Comment: No, not at all...just curious. One thing you should consider though is validating that value is a valid date before trying to filter

Comment: ok, so as you see, all the dates are a valide date and I get them like this : `find('td:first-child').text()`

Comment: Right but the keyup on the `<input>` is what I mean

Comment: Yes of course, I enter the right dates, but it doesn't work correctly, you can test it by your self in the code snippet ;)

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/51345745/125981